# How to programmatically show a new UI View conditionally using RubyMotion

Tags: ios, storyboard, transition, rubymotion

I have a storyboard created with 2 views. ViewController1 and ViewController2. What I want to be able to do is after a user fills in specific fields and clicks the "Login" button on view1, is transition the user to view2.

I have the button successfully linked up to a method that executes when it is pressed I am just not sure how to do the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is patterned off the standard IOS `Utility` template:

1) In your storyboard, set up a Modal segue from view controller 1 to 2.  Do this by control dragging from the view controller 1 icon (icon on the right at the bottom of your view controller) to view controller 2.  Select `modal` as the transition type and give this segue an identifier such as `ShowViewController2`.

2) In your implementation file for view controller 1, call this when the user presses `Log In`

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowViewController2", sender:self)
```

Then implement `prepareForSegue` in viewController1 to set up viewController2:

```
def prepareForSegue(segue, sender:sender)
    # call setters to pass data to the second view controller

    # set up a delegate pointer so that you can get back to VC1
    segue.destinationViewController.delegate = self
end
```

Also, implement a method in view controller 1 to be called when view controller 2 is done

```
# Come back here when view controller 2 is done, for instance if the
# user logs off.
def view_controller_2_is_done(sender)
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
end
```

For view controller 2, you'll want to set up a setter for `delegate` with

```
attr_accessor :delegate
```

When it is time to return to view controller 1 (ie when the user logs out), call:

```
@delegate.view_controller_2_is_done(self)
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up just finding and instantiating the viev. For example: 
 `solutionStoryboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithName("Storyboard", bundle:nil)
    myVC = solutionStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewId")
    self.presentModalViewController(myVC, animated:true)`

Comment: You'll probably still want to set up the delegate so that you can dismiss the modal view controller to return to view controller 1.